# Protractor - How to get actual values from the Repeater, not the Elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I am creating a Protractor script to test my quiz game that puts up random questions and answers, so I need my script to be able to figure out which answer is correct, so I can click it.

I can't figure out how to get the values directly from the model, instead of elements, since correct/incorrect is not exposed as an element on the page.

The model provides the answers in `Choice in Question.Choices`, and I need to find the Choice where `Choice.IsCorrect` is true. How do I get access to this value?

I wouldn't use the `element()` function, right?

```
element(by.repeater('Choice in Question.Choices').row(0).column('Choice.IsCorrect'))
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use [`element.all()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder) in conjunction with [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) and [`evaluate()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate):

```
var correctChoices = element.all(by.repeater('Choice in Question.Choices')).filter(function (elm) {
    return elm.evaluate('Choice.IsCorrect').then(function (value) {
        return value;
    });
});
```

As a result `correctChoices` would contain elements where `Choice.IsCorrect` is truthy.

---

If you need to get an array of values for the correct choices, use [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) and [`getAttribute()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute):

```
correctChoices.map(function (elm) {
    return elm.getAttribute('value');
});
```

or, if you need texts make use of [`getText()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText):

```
correctChoices.map(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText();
});
```